# Cant use one module in multiple places in single page

Tags: angular

For ex:

ObjectModule --> createModule --> render all attributes and input elements.

But my requirement:

When I am clicking a button in the same page it needs to open:

Button (click)--> objectModule -> createModule.
But it's throwing a warning message:

> WARNING in Circular dependency detected:
>   src/app/common/object/object/object.create.module.ts -> src/app/common/create/create.module.ts -> src/app/common/object/object/object.create.module.ts

Comment: As the error tells, you have a circular dependency (for instance module A needs Module B, and module B needs module C, and module C need module A). Without your showing how your modules are defined and import each other, that would be hard to tell more on how to restructure your code to avoid this.

Answer (score 1):

You have this error because:

- object.create.module.ts is importing create.module.ts
- create.module.ts is importing object.create.module.ts

This is called a circular dependency and is not allowed.

If you have components declared in one of the modules that both modules need than these could be separated out into a third module and then both modules could import the new module which would break the circular problem.